# TypeORM migration with nx-Monorepo Issue

Tags: typescript, migration, nestjs, typeorm, monorepo

I tried this a lot but now I think I need some help.
I have a nx-monorepo with angular-frontend and nestjs backend. Now I added a Postgres-SQL database with TypeORM. Everything is working fine, connection to Database is running, api-calls coming in, etc.
But I can't add the generate migration script. I added a run-command for my backend-project:

```
    "generate-migration": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "ts-node ../../node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n",
        "cwd": "apps/api"
      }
    }
```

I can run the command by "npm run api:generate-migration" but it results with this error:

> Error during migration generation:
> /apps/api/src/model/base.entity.ts:1
> import { __decorate, __metadata } from "tslib";
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:16)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:27)
> at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1056:23)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
> at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1059:12)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
> at /Users/IsabelleGlasmacher/Documents/Programme/save_easytonomy/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:41:22
> ERROR: Something went wrong in @nrwl/run-commands - Command failed: ts-node ../../node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate -n

ormConfig.json:

```
{
  ...
  "type": "postgres",
  "migrationsTableName": "migration",  
  "migrations": ["src/migration/*.ts"],
  "cli": {
    "migrationsDir": "src/migration"
  },
  "ssl": false
}
```

Does anybody know something about that and could help me? Please :)

Comment: Please add "migrations" parts of your TypeOrm.config to the question.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about this. I added it to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not..

Answer (score 4):

I am able to make a backend service using `NX@13`, `NestJS@8` and `TypeORM@0.2`,

In `project.json` of `game-api` , I added some commands like this

```
"generate-migration": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "ts-node --project tsconfig.app.json ../../node_modules/.bin/typeorm migration:generate --pretty -f .env.local",
        "cwd": "apps/game-api"
      }
    },
```

Code repository: https://github.com/coinconket/conketkemon

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is helpful for some people.
For the latest `nx@^14` , `@nestjs/*@^9` and `typeorm@~0.3`:

in your `project.json`. Note that `"apps/<app-name>"` can be applied to `"libs/<lib-name>"` as well

```
"typeorm": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "ts-node --project tsconfig.json <path-to-node_modules>/typeorm/cli",
        "cwd": "apps/<app-name>"
      }
    },
"mig-gen": {
      "builder": "@nrwl/workspace:run-commands",
      "outputs": [],
      "options": {
        "command": "nx run <app-name>:typeorm migration:generate <path-to-migration>/{args.name} -d <path-to-typeorm-config>/typeorm.config.ts",
        "cwd": "apps/<app-name>"
      }
    },
```

In your `typeorm.config.ts`

```
import { DataSource, DataSourceOptions } from 'typeorm';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { join } from 'path';

config({ path: '<path-to-env>/.env' });

const { DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_PORT, DB_NAME } =
  process.env;

export default new DataSource({
  type: DB_TYPE,
  host: DB_HOST,
  port: Number(DB_PORT),
  username: DB_USER,
  password: DB_PASS,
  database: DB_NAME,
  entities: [join(__dirname, '<path-to-entities>/*.entity.{ts,js}')],
  migrations: [join(__dirname, '<path-to-migration>/*{.ts,.js}')],
  synchronize: false,
} as DataSourceOptions);
```

in your `<path-to-app>/tsconfig.json`

make sure inside `compilerOptions{...}`, property `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` is set. Properties `module`,`types` and `target` may need to be set as well. See your `<root-workspace>/tsconfig.base.json` and documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig for reference

Finally in your terminal, you can run the command like this to generate your migration file

```
nx run <app-name>:mig-gen --name=whatever-makes-you-happy
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"module": "CommonJS"` to `compilerOptions` in tsconfig.app.json of the related nx app fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Can you please tell me where exactly did you but the module commonjs? I have like 10 tsconfig files in the project. 