# Sharing Environment configuration with NestJS and TypeORM but migrations do not generate

Tags: typescript, migration, nestjs, typeorm, nrwl-nx

I have been able to get the ConfigService to work with my TypeORM (v0.3.7) configuration, so my environment (.env) file is being written, and works with my NestJS (v8.4.7) application in a Nrwl NX (v14.4.2) mono repository.  My database access via NestJS is working fine.

I have created a database configuration class (database.configuration.ts) which gets my information for the database connection from the .env file using the NestJS Configuration module.

database.configuration.ts

```
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

export default class DatabaseConfiguration {
    static GetORMConfiguration(ConfigService_: ConfigService): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
        return {
            type: 'mysql',
            host: ConfigService_.get('DB_SERVER_HOST') || 'localhost',
            port: parseInt(ConfigService_.get('DB_SERVER_PORT'), 10) || 3306,
            username: ConfigService_.get('DB_USER') || 'username',
            password: ConfigService_.get('DB_PASSWORD') || 'password',
            database: ConfigService_.get('DB_DATABASE') || 'dbname',
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: false,
            migrationsRun: false,
            logging: ['error', 'schema', 'warn'],
            maxQueryExecutionTime: 1000,
            logger: 'file',
        };
    }
}

export const DatabaseConfigurationAsync: TypeOrmModuleAsyncOptions = {
    imports: [ConfigModule],
    useFactory: async (ConfigService_: ConfigService): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => DatabaseConfiguration.GetORMConfiguration(ConfigService_),
    inject: [ConfigService]
};
```

Then I have updated by app.module.ts to import and use this information, based on [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607560/nestjs-typeorm-configuration-works-but-not-with-configservice):

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

import { DatabaseConfigurationAsync } from './database.configuration';

import { AdminCodesModule } from './admin-codes/admin-codes.module';

import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync(DatabaseConfigurationAsync),

        AdminCodesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I have a simple definition then for the Administration Codes, to simply have a database.  Working with the API from the controller, service, etc., I do receive all my data back.  However, when I try to generate the migrations, I get an error that I cannot resolve no matter how I keep trying to change the code.

Trying to run the commands (via npm and package.json or the bash shell):

```
npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate -d ./app/database.configuration.ts ./migrations/admincodes
```

or

```
npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:generate -d ./app/database.configuration.ts admincodes
```

gives an error:

```
Error during migration generation:
Error: Unable to open file: "repo\apps\api\src\app\database.configuration.ts". Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have tried changing this many ways, including even moving to `type: module` in my package.json, and using `typeorm-ts-node-esm` to run the generation, but each version fails with some part of the import error, or with `type: module` the export line fails.

I cannot use the `type: module` in my package.json as that breaks other functionality in the NestJS application.

Comment: You can refer to my answer here to get some clues. Hope that helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302398/typeorm-migration-with-nx-monorepo-issue/73834278#73834278

Answer (score 0):

The error specify that the path is incorrect, and can't open the file.
check your dist folder, and check where the file is generate when you build your app.

I think you have to add `/src` in your path:
./src/app/database.configuration.ts ./migrations/admincodes.

Answer (score 0):

**this is the simple way i configure it**

npm i @nestjs/config

```
    @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      name: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          type: 'mysql',
          host: configService.get(`DATABASE_HOST`),
          port: configService.get(`DATABASE_PORT`),
          username: configService.get('DB_USER'),
          database: configService.get('DATABASE_NAME'),
          password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          entities: [__dirname + '/../entities/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: false,
          logging: true,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
```

Comment: I will have to try this in a new project in the future. When I could not get it working, I moved to Mikro-ORM which did not not have the issue.